# office.js dialogAPIs opening full sized window even after specifying the size

Tags: office-js

I'm using `office.js` dialogAPI for authentication purpose.
It is working fine on windows machine but displaying full sized window on mac even after specifying the size.
I'm using mac OS sierra and excel version 15.30.

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(url, { height: 90, width: 35, requireHTTPS: true }, dialogCallback);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was indeed a regression that has been fixed in build 15.31.0(17021600). The build was released on [February 16](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Release-notes-for-February-2017-ed2da564-6d53-4542-9954-7e3209681a41#bkmk_feb2017) and should be available if you check for the latest updates.

Comment: Thank you @Humberto for the comment. I'll check for that

Answer (score 0):

The signature of the displayDialogAsync [Office.DialogOptions interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.dialogoptions?view=common-js-preview) is different. You don't need "requireHTTPS" option, instead you should specify "displayInIframe" option.